# trying to retrieve one object based on conditions values using Android REST API

Tags: json, android-activity

I’m using Parse.com, and trying to retrieve one object based on conditions values using Android REST API

here is a snippet from the Parse documentation for the REST API

```
curl -X GET \
     -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: MYAPPID" \
     -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: MYRESTKEY" \
     -G \
     --data-urlencode 'where={"$relatedTo":{"object":{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Post","objectId":"8TOXdXf3tz"},"key":"likes"}}' \
 https://api.parse.com/1/users
```

How can I achieve this in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's curl based api, you have to explicitly pass all its parameter.
I recommending you to first test api using client application like Postman.

-X define term like GET,POST,PUT,DELETE

-H define header, which has key-value form data separated by ":" sign.

-G When used, all data to be used in an HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.

Pass all these parameters and test it, once it is working fine then implement to your application.