# Android REST API - Parse Server

Tags: android, parsing, retrofit

What is the way to send queries to Parse Server with Retrofit, rest api.

I found something like that:
[trying to retrieve one object based on conditions values using Android REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118640/trying-to-retrieve-one-object-based-on-conditions-values-using-android-rest-api)

But i don't understand how can I configure it for my kind queries in android:

```
@GET("classes/Mentor")
Call<OneMentorResponse> getMentor(@Query("where") 
String where, @Header("X-Parse-Session-Token") String token);
```

Answer (score 0):

pass a HashMap to query.

```
HashMap<String,String> sendKey=new HashMap<>;
sendKey.put("yourKey","yourValue");
yourApiInterface.getMentor(new JSONObject(sendKeyValue).toString()).new CallBack<OneMentorResponse response>{}
```

and implement the response and failure methods.
and also pass your header the way you are doing it.